# Find out redirected location of Javascript source

Tags: javascript, php, redirect

My HTML page has a `<script>` tag, which embeds a Javascript source file indirectly through a PHP script, e.g.

```
<script src="http://my.server.com/myjs.php?version=1"></script>
```

Based on the parameters to `myjs.php` (version only being an example) the PHP file simply sets the location

```
header("Location: version/1/mynewfile.js");
```

and the browser then automatically loads `mynewfile.js`.

Unfortunately `mynuewfile.js` needs to know the URL where it is loaded from, e.g. ***http://my.server.com/version/1/mynewfile.js***.

Without using redirection, the globally executed code in mynewfile.js simply inspects the src property of the first  element. Unfortunately, this only returns ***http://my.server.com/myjs.php?version=1***. How can mynewjsfile.js get the real (redirected) URI of the script?

Of course, the PHP file could "simply" read the JS file and set a global variable to the JS file, but redirection is a really elegant solution and should be kept if possible.